# Using multiple lex files and combining it into one while executing

Tags: c, lex

I have multiple lex files namely, keywords.l, identifier.l and literals.l

keywords.l:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
/*#include "../yacc/grammer.tab.h"*/
%}

class "class"
from "from"
None "None"
continue "continue"
global "global"
pass "pass"
def "def"
if "if"
raise "raise"
del "del"
import "import"
return "return"
as "as"
elif "elif"
try "try"
assert "assert"
else "else"
while "while"
async "async"
except "except"
lambda "lambda"
with "with"
await "await"
finally "finally"
nonlocal "nonlocal"
yield "yield"
break "break"
for "for"

%%
{class} {printf("keyword ");}
{from} {printf("keyword ");}
{None} {printf("keyword ");}
{continue} {printf("keyword ");}
{global} {printf("keyword ");}
{pass} {printf("keyword ");}
{def} {printf("keyword ");}
{if} {printf("keyword ");}
{raise} {printf("keyword ");}
{del} {printf("keyword ");}
{import} {printf("keyword ");}
{return} {printf("keyword ");}
{as} {printf("keyword ");}
{elif} {printf("keyword ");}
{try} {printf("keyword ");}
{assert} {printf("keyword ");}
{else} {printf("keyword ");}
{while} {printf("keyword ");}
{async} {printf("keyword ");}
{except} {printf("keyword ");}
{lambda} {printf("keyword ");}
{with} {printf("keyword ");}
{await} {printf("keyword ");}
{finally} {printf("keyword ");}
{nonlocal} {printf("keyword ");}
{yield} {printf("keyword ");}
{break} {printf("keyword ");}
{for} {printf("keyword ");}

%%


int yywrap() { 
  return 1; 
}
```

identifier.l

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "../yacc/grammer.tab.h"

typedef struct SymbolTable{
  char token[10];
  char attr[100];
  char type[10];
} SymbolTable;

SymbolTable ST[1000];
int STn=0;

void printST(){
  int i;
  printf("\nPrinting Symbol Table ");
  for(i=0;i<STn;i++){
    printf("\n%s : %s",ST[i].token, ST[i].attr);
  }
}

int installID(char *a, char *t){
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<STn;i++){
    if((strcmp(ST[i].token, "ID")==0)&&(strcmp(ST[i].attr, a)==0)){
      return i;
    }
  }
  strcpy(ST[STn].token,"ID");
  strcpy(ST[STn].attr,a);
  strcpy(ST[STn].type,t);
  STn++;
  return STn-1;
}

%}

id [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*

%%

%union {
    char *lexeme;
    int value;
}

%token <lexeme> ID

{id} {
    printf("\nIdentifier : %s ", yytext);
    int a = installID(yytext, NULL);
    yylval.lexeme = strdup(yytext);
    return ID;
}

%%

int yywrap() { 
  return 1; 
}
```

literals.l

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "../yacc/grammer.tab.h"

typedef struct SymbolTable{
  char token[10];
  char attr[100];
  char type[10];
}SymbolTable;

SymbolTable ST[1000];
int STn=0;

void printST(){
  int i;
  printf("\nPrinting Symbol Table ");
  for(i=0;i<STn;i++){
    printf("\n%s : %s",ST[i].token, ST[i].attr);
  }
}

int installLit(char *b, char *t){
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<STn;i++){
    if((strcmp(ST[i].token, "NUM")==0)&&(strcmp(ST[i].attr, b)==0)){
      return i;
    }
  }
  strcpy(ST[STn].token,"LITERAL");
  strcpy(ST[STn].attr,b);
  strcpy(ST[STn].type,t);
  STn++;
  return STn-1;
}

%}

int [-]?[0-9]+
float [-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?
bool (True|False)
str (\"([^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\")|('([^'\\\\]|\\\\.)*')

%%
{int} {printf("\nInteger : %s ",yytext);
      int a = installLit(yytext,"INT");
      yylval.value = = strdup(yytext);
      return LITERAL;}

{str} {printf("String ");
      int a = installLit(yytext,"STR");
      yylval.value = = strdup(yytext);
      return LITERAL;}

{float} {printf("Float ");
      int a = installLit(yytext,"FLOAT");
      yylval.value = = strdup(yytext);
      return LITERAL;}

{bool} {printf("Boolean ");
      int a = installLit(yytext,"BOOL");
      yylval.value = = strdup(yytext);
      return LITERAL;}

%union {
    char *lexeme;
    int value;
}

%token <value> LITERAL
%%

int yywrap() { 
  return 1; 
}
```

I want to combine these 3 lex files into a single file like how we import packages/file in C, python, etc.

I tried doing so

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "../yacc/grammer.tab.h";
#include "keywords.l"
#include "literals.l"
#include "identifier.l"
%}

%%

%union {
    char *lexeme;
    int value;
}

%token <lexeme> ID

%%

int yywrap(){
  return 1;
}
```

But while importing, the imported files are considered as C files not a .l files.

```
flex tokens.l

gcc lex.yy.c
tokens.l:5:33: warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive
 #include "../yacc/grammer.tab.h";
                                 ^
In file included from tokens.l:6:0:
keywords.l:1:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '%' token
 %{
 ^
keywords.l:8:7: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before string constant
 class "class"
       ^
keywords.l:38:9: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {class} {printf("keyword ");}
         ^
keywords.l:39:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {from} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:39:8: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {from} {printf("keyword ");}
        ^
keywords.l:40:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {None} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:40:8: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {None} {printf("keyword ");}
        ^
keywords.l:41:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {continue} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:41:12: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {continue} {printf("keyword ");}
            ^
keywords.l:42:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {global} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:42:10: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {global} {printf("keyword ");}
          ^
keywords.l:43:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {pass} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:43:8: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {pass} {printf("keyword ");}
        ^
keywords.l:44:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {def} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:44:7: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {def} {printf("keyword ");}
       ^
keywords.l:45:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {if} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:45:6: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {if} {printf("keyword ");}
      ^
keywords.l:46:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {raise} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:46:9: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {raise} {printf("keyword ");}
         ^
keywords.l:47:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {del} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:47:7: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {del} {printf("keyword ");}
       ^
keywords.l:48:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {import} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:48:10: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {import} {printf("keyword ");}
          ^
keywords.l:49:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {return} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:49:10: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {return} {printf("keyword ");}
          ^
keywords.l:50:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {as} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:50:6: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {as} {printf("keyword ");}
      ^
keywords.l:51:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {elif} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:51:8: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {elif} {printf("keyword ");}
        ^
keywords.l:52:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {try} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:52:7: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {try} {printf("keyword ");}
       ^
keywords.l:53:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {assert} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:53:10: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {assert} {printf("keyword ");}
          ^
keywords.l:54:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {else} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:54:8: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {else} {printf("keyword ");}
        ^
keywords.l:55:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {while} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:55:9: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {while} {printf("keyword ");}
         ^
keywords.l:56:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {async} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:56:9: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {async} {printf("keyword ");}
         ^
keywords.l:57:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {except} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:57:10: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {except} {printf("keyword ");}
          ^
keywords.l:58:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {lambda} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:58:10: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {lambda} {printf("keyword ");}
          ^
keywords.l:59:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {with} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:59:8: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {with} {printf("keyword ");}
        ^
keywords.l:60:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {await} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:60:9: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {await} {printf("keyword ");}
         ^
keywords.l:61:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {finally} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:61:11: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {finally} {printf("keyword ");}
           ^
keywords.l:62:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {nonlocal} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:62:12: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {nonlocal} {printf("keyword ");}
            ^
keywords.l:63:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {yield} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:63:9: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {yield} {printf("keyword ");}
         ^
keywords.l:64:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {break} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:64:9: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {break} {printf("keyword ");}
         ^
keywords.l:65:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {for} {printf("keyword ");}
 ^
keywords.l:65:7: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {for} {printf("keyword ");}
       ^
keywords.l:67:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '%' token
 %%
 ^
In file included from tokens.l:7:0:
literals.l:1:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '%' token
 %{
 ^
In file included from tokens.l:7:0:
literals.l:40:5: error: expected identifier or '(' before '[' token
 int [-]?[0-9]+
     ^
literals.l:43:1: error: stray '\' in program
 str (\"([^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\")|('([^'\\\\]|\\\\.)*')
 ^
literals.l:43:7: warning: missing terminating " character
 str (\"([^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\")|('([^'\\\\]|\\\\.)*')
       ^
literals.l:43:1: error: missing terminating " character
 str (\"([^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\")|('([^'\\\\]|\\\\.)*')
 ^
literals.l:46:7: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {int} {printf("\nInteger : %s ",yytext);
       ^
literals.l:51:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {str} {printf("String ");
 ^
literals.l:51:7: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {str} {printf("String ");
       ^
literals.l:56:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {float} {printf("Float ");
 ^
literals.l:56:9: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {float} {printf("Float ");
         ^
literals.l:61:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {bool} {printf("Boolean ");
 ^
literals.l:61:8: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {bool} {printf("Boolean ");
        ^
literals.l:66:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '%' token
 %union {
 ^
literals.l:71:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '%' token
 %token <value> LITERAL
 ^
In file included from tokens.l:8:0:
identifier.l:1:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '%' token
 %{
 ^
In file included from tokens.l:8:0:
identifier.l:40:5: error: 'a' undeclared here (not in a function)
 id [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*
     ^
identifier.l:40:7: error: 'zA' undeclared here (not in a function)
 id [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*
       ^
identifier.l:40:10: error: 'Z_' undeclared here (not in a function)
 id [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*
          ^
identifier.l:40:19: error: 'Z_0' undeclared here (not in a function)
 id [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*
                   ^
identifier.l:40:25: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
 id [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*
                         ^
identifier.l:49:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '%' token
 %token <lexeme> ID
 ^
identifier.l:51:6: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {id} {
      ^
identifier.l:58:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '%' token
 %%
 ^
tokens.l: In function 'yylex':
tokens.l:18:1: error: expected expression before '<' token
 %token <lexeme> ID
```

Kindly help

Comment: What you want to do isn't really possible. And the errors you get are because you include the lexer files as they were C header files, which they are not.

Comment: You may want to open and use the lex files, not try to import as header file.

Comment: @LORDTEK is there any other way to do so?

Comment: @HelloWorld As far as I know, the only way is open the files, read them and justify as your needed. The files are seems like dictionary type. Hope to help.

Comment: You will need to combine the three files into one.  Or, compile them so that you have three lexical analyzers, such as `xxlex()`, `yylex()` and `zzlex()`.  But a single file that is a non-trivial merge of the three files is most likely what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Lex and Flex do not preprocess their inputs with the C preprocessor, nor do they provide any mechanism analogous the the preprocessor's `#include` directive or the (quite different) behavior of a Python `import` statement.  Lex and its work-alikes require the entire scanner definition to be presented in a single input file.

> I tried doing so
>
> ```
> %{
> #include<stdio.h>
> #include<stdlib.h>
> #include<string.h>
> #include "../yacc/grammer.tab.h";
> #include "keywords.l"
> #include "literals.l"
> #include "identifier.l"
> %}
> ```

> But while importing, the imported files are considered as C files not a .l files.

C does not have a Pythonesque *import* feature.  The C preprocessor has external-file *inclusion* capability, which has considerably different semantics.

Anyway, Lex is a C code generator.  Anything inside a `%{ ... %}` block is carried through verbatim to the output C source file.  Thus, your

> ```
> #include "keywords.l"
> ```

*etc*. are processed during C compilation (not Lex scanner generation), according to the semantics of the C preprocessor. As a result, yes, the C compiler attempts to interpret the contents of those files as C source code.

> Kindly help

Combine all your .l files into one.  And as you do so, pay attention to the fact that the entries in the rules (middle) section of the input are order-sensitive.  This will make a difference for you, because all of your keywords also satisfy the rule for an `id`.

Also be sure to remove the duplicate definitions of `yywrap()`.  The overall scanner can have only one.

Comment: Is it possible in bison(yacc)? I.e splitting files and combing?

Comment: No, @StackOverflow, Bison and yacc do not provide such a feature either.